# Searching javascript array of objects based on multiple predicates (or) - lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of objects that I want to search to find matching results. Currently I am using lodash and my query looks like this:

```
let toPush = _.findIndex(result, {itemNumber: queryArray[j][0]})
```

I want to edit the predicate to search for multiple properties, but using an or predicate, so it will look like:

```
let toPush = _.findIndex(result, {itemNumber: queryArray[j][0] || listings.urlId : queryArray[j][0]})
```

How can I use an or operator with lodash?

I don't necessarily need to use lodash vs vanilla js, also instead of the index, it can return the whole object.

**edit**

This is what I resulted to in the end:

```
let toPush = _.findIndex(result, {listings: [{urlId: queryArray[j][0]}]}) > -1
    ? _.findIndex(result, {listings: [{urlId: queryArray[j][0]}]})
    :_.findIndex(result, {itemNumber:queryArray[j][0]}) > -1
        ? _.findIndex(result, {itemNumber:queryArray[j][0]})
        : _.findIndex(result, {productIdentifiers: [{productIdentifier: queryArray[j][0]}]}) > -1
            ? _.findIndex(result, {productIdentifiers: [{productIdentifier: queryArray[j][0]}]})
            : -1
```

If anyone can chime in on a better way I'd really appreciate it. Based on the answers so far I haven't been able to get anything else working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a comparator function as the second argument where you can put whatever logic you want:

```
let toPush = _.findIndex(result, function (item) {
  // put logic in here, return true if the item matches or false otherwise
  return (item.itemNumber === queryArray[j][0] || item.listings.some(listing => listing.urlId === queryArray[j][0]));
});
```

This is virtually identical to vanilla JS:

```
let toPush = result.findIndex(function (item) {
  // put logic in here, return true if the item matches or false otherwise
  return (item.itemNumber === queryArray[j][0] || item.listings.some(listing => listing.urlId === queryArray[j][0]));
});
```

Comment: Listings is a nested array of objects, I'm trying to avoid a bunch of if statements and loops. I have 3 predicates at the moment, but may need to add more in the future.

Comment: Oh, so you will need a way to dig into the sub array like [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) used above.  There's probably a lodash version of some, too.

Answer (score 0):

Runnable piece of code with pattern that I would use:

```js
const result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

console.log(result.findIndex((x) => [3,5].some((y) => x == y)))
```

Of course you need to replace `[3,5]` with values you wish to check against.

Answer (score 0):

**Loadash Approach**

```js
let users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];
let result = _.find(users, function(u) {
  return u.age <= 40 && u.active; 
});
console.log(result);
```

*N.B. Please note that the `find` funtion will return undefined if found nothing*

**ES16 Approach**

```js
let users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

let result = users.find(function(u){
  return u.age<=40 && u.active && u.user.includes('r');
});

console.log(result);
```

*N.B. Like lodash `find` function `ES find` will also return undefined if nothing found.*